# Using Word what is the proper way to define a non splittable text block

Tags: microsoft-word

Word allows one to insert page breaks. But is it possible to prevent a block of text to be splited by a page change: Is it possible to force this block of text to choose "by itself" to stand fully on one of both pages ?

Comment: yes, there is. See "keep a paragraph on one page" and "keep paragraphs together" [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Keep-text-together-af94e5b8-3a5a-4cb0-9c53-dea56b43d96d?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1)

Comment: That's the right answer @Máté Juhász, why do you comment ?

Comment: because I don't have time to write a proper answer. It should be more detailed than just recommending a link.

Comment: Just put it as is or copy-past the content of the "Keep a paragraph on one page" block of your link, and I will valid your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To prevent text to be split across pages you have two Paragraph settings:

- "keep lines together" to keep the whole paragraph on the same page
- "keep with next" to keep multiple paragraphs together

You can read more on the topic in [office help](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Keep-text-together-af94e5b8-3a5a-4cb0-9c53-dea56b43d96d?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1)